# grep output of `--help` in MacOS

Tags: macos, grep

In Ubuntu Linux, grepping the output of a `--help` command works as expected:

```
# pytest --help  | grep python

                        expression. An expression is a python evaluatable
  --pyargs              try to interpret all arguments as python
# ... list continues
```

But in macOS, that hangs.

If I run `pytest --help > output.txt` and then `cat output.txt | grep python`, it works as expected.

What can I do to in macOS to search the output of `--help` in a single command?

Comment: What is pytest then? Greping works fine under MacOS like "$ mysql --help | grep host" or "$ python --help | grep python" both returns the expected result.

Comment: You're correct. That's confusing. `pytest` is a fairly standard library, and `pytest --help > output.txt` does write to the file. Any thoughts on what could cause the differing behavior?

Comment: I found pytest and installed it and "$ pytest --help  | grep python" works fine. Anything special with your grep command?

Comment: Thanks for chasing it down. You're right. It's a `fish` issue - `bash` works as expected

Comment: This is the same issue - that fish overrides grep - as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305261/output-pipe-waits-for-eof-in-fish